# Cassandra system.log messages documentation

Tags: logging, notifications, cassandra

We start to use Cassandra in production so we need to configure our log analyzer for important log events notification and alerts. 
Is there any documentation with the most critical log messages?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any documentation, but all messages have a severity associated with them - INFO, WARN or ERROR (with the standard verbosity settings) that you can grep for.  Not all ERROR level messages need any intervention though.  You could try by notifying on errors and whitelisting the benign ones.

Comment: Another idea is to be ready for some critical issues.
Just now we try to crash Cassandra in different scenarios, but errors' documentation will be very helpful.